Python typing is rejecting override of a property with a child of its type
Here is an example of my issue:
class Foo:
    pass

class FooChild(Foo):
    pass

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop: Foo

class BarChild(Bar):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop: FooChild = FooChild()

Here I have a warning on the override of the prop property:
"prop" overrides symbol of same name in class "Bar"  
    Variable is mutable so its type is invariant  
        Override type "FooChild" is not the same as base type "Foo"

I am confused as to why this is an error. A child would implement its parent, so why can I not override it in this case?

Because instance variable is mutable, as the error says. It's perfectly legal to do self.prop = Foo() in some other method of Parent, so the annotation with any other type, including some Foo subtype, doesn't make sense.
